# Puppet: Change file on readonly filesystem

Tags: puppet

I'd like to use puppet to manage files on read-only filesystems.
So I need to remount the filesystem read-write before modification, and read only afterwards.

I made two exec resources :

```
exec { 'mount rw':
  command => "/sbin/mount -uw /",
  refreshonly => true,
}
exec { 'mount ro':
  command => "/sbin/mount -ur /",
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

Obviously, I want them to be called by my `file`, only if the file is modified.

```
file { '/root/puppettest':
  content => template('mfs/puppettest'),
  require => Exec['mount rw'],
  notify  => Exec['mount ro'],
}
```

My problem : `mount rw` is never executed, as `require` is not considered as a refresh.

How can I do something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [`transition`](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/transition) module to accomplish this.

Something like:

```
transition { 'mount rw':
  resource   => Exec['mount rw'],
  attributes => { refreshonly => false },
  prior_to   => File['/root/puppettest'],
}
```

This should then flip the `refreshonly` attribute from `true` to `false` (and therefore make your first `exec` resource unconditionally run if the file needs to be changed.

The problem you have is that if the filesystem is mounted read-write and the files match what Puppet expects, it will never mount the filesystem read-only again. So you could probably just use the `mount` resource and use the `transition` resource to change the `options` attribute, something like:

```
file { '/root/puppettest':
  content => ...
  before  => Mount['/'],
}

transition { 'remount / rw':
  resource   => Mount['/'],
  attributes => { options => 'rw,...' },
  prior_to   => File['/root/pupppettest'],
}

mount { '/':
  ... # Rest of the options skipped for brevity
  options  => 'ro,...',
  remounts => true,
}
```

You're then modelling the intended state of the system.

Comment: I can't get the official mount class to work under OpenBSD for remounting partitions, I am stuck with the exec one. Anyway, your idea to use transition with refreshonly => false works and is idempotent. TYVM !

Comment: As a fellow OpenBSD user I've run into a few edge cases where Puppet's support is slightly lacking. I wasn't aware remounting didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The final code, in case someone needs it.
Credits to @bodgit

```
exec { 'mount rw':
  command => "/sbin/mount -uw /",
  refreshonly => true,
}

transition { 'remount rw':
  resource => Exec['mount rw'],
  attributes => { refreshonly => false },
  prior_to => File['/root/puppettest'],
}

file { '/root/puppettest':
  content => template('mfs/puppettest'),
  notify  => Exec['mount ro'],
}

exec { 'mount ro':
  command => "/sbin/mount -ur /",
  refreshonly => true,
}
```